# fast SQL query for join with first record of a set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

suppose there are below tables

Table A

```
WorkId       DateA
-----        -------
1           01/01/2017
```

Table B

```
WorkId       DateB        Flag    User
-----        -------      ----    -----
1           01/12/2016     N       u1
1           03/12/2016     N       u2
1           01/01/2017     Y       u2
1           02/01/2017     Y       u3
1           02/01/2017     Y       u3
1           05/01/2017     N       u4 
1           05/01/2017     N       u5 
1           06/01/2017     N       u5
1           10/01/2017     Y       u5 
1           12/01/2017     Y       u6
1           12/01/2017     N       u7
```

every record in Table A should be joined to a record in Table B based on  TableA.WorkId = TableB.WorkId and TableA.DateA = TableB.DateB (this join has always Flag = y in TableB). Based on this join I should get WorkId/TableA.DateA and TableB.User (user1 in result below). For example, above record in Table A is joined by third row of Table B.

Then I need to get first record from Table B which its Flag is N and has minimum date after DateA. Which in this example is sixth record in Table A. Then I need to add this user (user2) and date (DateB) to the result:

Result

```
WorkId    DateA        DateB         User1     User2
-----     -------      ------        -----     -----
1         01/01/2017   05/01/2017    u2         u4
```

I have used below query

```
WITH c AS (
SELECT a.WorkId, a.DateA, b.User AS User1
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
ON a.WorkId = b.WorkId AND a.DateA = b.DateB
),

c1 AS (
SELECT c.*, b.DateB, b.User AS User2
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.WorkId, c.DateA ORDER BY b.DateB) AS rn
FROM c
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB b
ON c.WorkId = b.WorkId AND b.Flag = 'N' AND b.DateB > c.DateA
)

SELECT *
FROM c1
WHERE rn = 1
```

I have two indexes WorkId + Data and Data on each table.

The problem is that the query is slow and it becomes extremely slow when tables are quite large. Do you know a faster code. Thanks.

Comment: If you press CTRL-L, the query planner will suggest indexes. Do you have any indexes? How many rows are in each table?

Comment: If u can share execution plan I can help u

Comment: @Bob . . . Do you have a unique id in each table?

Comment: no these are staging tables and i didn't create any unique id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to formulate the query:

```
select a.*, b2.date as date2, b.user as user1, bnext.user as user2
from tableA a join
     tableB b 
     on a.workid = b.workid and a.date = b.date outer apply
     (select top 1 b2.*
      from tableB b2
      where b2.workId = a.workid and b2.date > a.date and b2.flag = 'N'
      order by b2.date desc
     ) bnext;
```

For the `join`, you want an index on `tableB(workId, date)` -- the keys can be in either order.  For the subquery, you want an index on `tableB(workId, date, flag, user)`.  This one query is really all you need.

Hmmm.   There is another way that might be faster:

```
select workid, date1, date as date2, user1, user as user2
from (select ab.*, min(date) over (partition by workid, grp) as date1,
             max(user1) over (partition by workid, grp) as user1,
             row_number() over (partition by workid, grp, flag) as seqnum
      from (select b.*,
                   sum(case when a.workid is not null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by b.workid order by b.date) as grp,
                   max(case when a.workid is not null then user end) as user1
            from tableB b left join
                 tableA a
                 on a.workid = b.workid and a.date = b.date
           ) ab
     ) ab
where seqnum = 1 and flag = 'N';
```

This is much trickier and it depends on rows in A not overlapping one another in the matches on B.  The idea is that it finds the match in B, then it uses window functions to find the first row with a flag of N.

Comment: many thanks Gordon. I used your first approach and it took around 30 seconds when tableA has 3m and tableB has 50m records. my approach took around 40 minutes. the index on tableB you mentioned had no effect.